# pass value to <input> after every for loop in methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have a `for loop` where I get unique numbers of a array these are named `this.number` - I `input.push()` my `b-form-input` (in this example) 3 times.

Every time I'm inputing a new `b-form-input` I want to pass the first and then of course my next number of `this.number` to my input that it will be shown there.

How can I do that? Thank You!

template:

```
<div v-for="(id, index) in inputs" :key="index">
  <b-form-input type="number" v-model="id.number" :value="id.number" @input="searchNumber(id, index)" ></b-form-input>
</div>
```

my script:

```
methods: {
  inputValue() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      this.number= (String(this.data[i].number));
      this.inputs.push({});

      console.log(this.number);
    }
  }
},

data() {
  return {
    inputs: [{}],
  }
},
```

my `console.log(this.number)`

```
1111
2222
3333
```

So `1111` should be `v-model/value of b-form-input 0`, `2222` should be `v-model/value of b-form-input 1` and `3333` should be `v-model/value of b-form-input 2`

Comment: Your `methods` is invalid. Please, update the question with the correct version of `methods`

Comment: forgot my method name. But at least I just need to know how is it possible to push ```this.number``` each time with my ```input.push()``` to my ```b-form-input```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood what you are trying to do is:

1. Render 3 inputs
2. When user inputs in input number 2 it updates the input number 2

You have your code organized in a way that is difficult to follow what is going on. My suggestion is to have a function that is triggered when an input emits a `input` event and then pass the index (almost what you have with `searchNumber`)

```html
<div v-for="(id, index) in inputs" :key="index">
  <b-form-input type="number" :value="id.number" @input="onInput($event, index)" ></b-form-input>
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
  onInput(input, index) {
    this.inputs[index].number = input;
  }
}
```

Note that I have removed `v-model` from your `b-form-input`. Now we only have `value` and `@input`.